# C++ how to print the first 10 and last 10 elements of an array?

Tags: c++, loops, printing

im trying to print the first 10 and the last 10 elements of an array. My attempt below returns the following in an infinite loop

```
Word: Count 0
```

```
void printarrayString(std::string arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    std::cout << "***first 10 elements***" << std::endl;
    for (i = 10; i < size; i++)//print first 10 elements 
    std::cout << "Word: " << wordArr[i] << "  " << "Occurs: " << countArr[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "***last 10 elements***" << std::endl;
    for(j = 10; j < size-10; j-- ) //print last 10 elements
    std::cout << "Word: " << wordArr[i] << "  " << "Occurs: " << countArr[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

How can i fix the loops so loop 1 prints the first 10 elements of wordArr and countArr and loop 2 prints the last 10 elements? Thankyou

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on that function. For example, what is the index of the first element you print in the loops (*both* of the loops)?

Comment: In case you didn't realise, you are using j as the iterator and i as the indexer in your reverse loop. Is that a typo?

Comment: Note that `arr` is not an array. It is a pointer to `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the indices wrong. In C++ (and even in most programming languages) the base, or first element is located at index 0 (ever wonder why?). So, to print the first n elements, you need to iterate from `i = 0` to `i = n - 1`, aka `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` and to print the previous n elements, you need to iterate from `i = n - 1` to `i = 0`, aka `for(int i = n - 1; i >=0; i--)`.

---

> PS: 0 based indexing => no extra calculations to find the first element after locating the base ;)

Answer (score 0):

As above, in C++, array indices are zero-based. Also, you should check whether you actually have 10 elements. And 'wordArr' and 'countArr' are undefined, perhaps declared elsewhere. Here's my guess at what you want to achieve. The std::min() function comes from the algorithm std library.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printarrayString(string arr[], int size)
{
    //Check we have 10 elements. If not, use fewer
    int nElementsToPrint = min(10,size);

    //First 10 (if possible) elements
    for(int i =0; i < nElementsToPrint; i++)
    {
         cout << "Word: " << arr[i] << " Occurs: " << i;
    }
    cout << endl;

    //etc etc 
}
```

You can do the last 10 elements in the same way, though you haven't said if you want them in the same order as in the string (starting at (size-nElementsToPrint) and forwards with i++), or the last element first (starting at (size-1) and backwards with i--).